# Different actions for the embedded and the containing element

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor in a table. I would need an action for the click on the anchor, and another for the click on the table ('s cell). But if I click on the anchor, both of the actions will be run off. How can I disable the table's action when I click on the anchor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$('anchor').bind('click', function(ev) {

  ev.stopPropagation();

  //... your code

  return false;


});
```